# Better option than "errno" for file IO error handling

Tags: c++, c++11, io, error-handling

I have the following method for opening a file:

```
void TankFile::OpenForReading(const std::string & filename)
{
    assert(!filename.empty());

    errno = 0;
    file.exceptions(0); // Don't throw
    file.open(filename, (std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary));

    if (!file.is_open() || !file.good())
    {
        const char * errorStr = strerror(errno);
        throw TankFileError(Format("Failed to open Tank file \"%s\": '%s'", filename.c_str(), errorStr));
    }
}
```

The objective here is to attempt to open a file and throw `TankFileError` with a proper error description on failure. The caller will be expecting this exception type.

Everything works fine and I get a nice error message like this if the exception is thrown:

> Failed to open Tank file "unexistent_file": 'No such file or directory'

But what I don't like in that block is having to use the `errno` global and `strerror()`.

A way around it would be to let the stream throw an exception, then catch it, get the error message from the `what()` member and re-throw with `TankFileError`, but I find this solution also a bit hackish, plus, in the tests I did, the resulting error message from `std::fstream::failure` was pretty cryptic:

```
void TankFile::OpenForReading(const std::string & filename)
{
    assert(!filename.empty());

    try
    {
        file.exceptions(std::fstream::failbit);
        file.open(filename, (std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary));
    }
    catch (std::fstream::failure & err)
    {
        throw TankFileError(Format("Failed to open Tank file \"%s\": '%s'", filename.c_str(), err.what()));
    }
}
```

Produced the error message:

> Failed to open Tank file "unexistent_file": 'ios_base::clear: unspecified iostream_category error'.

Is there a better way to implement this? I was hoping that the new C++11 `system_error` library would provide a way to query this kind of error messages, but from what I've seen, you still have to pass `errno` around to get an error string.

Comment: +1 This is a great question. I also noticed that the error messages returned by `std::ios::failure` are pretty useless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I currently don't see any seamless alternative to using errno and ::strerror;.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <system_error>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <cstring> // strerror

#include <fstream>

#if defined(_LIBCPP_VERSION) && (_LIBCPP_VERSION >= 1000)
#define HAS_IOS_BASE_FAILURE_DERIVED_FROM_SYSTEM_ERROR 1
#else
#define HAS_IOS_BASE_FAILURE_DERIVED_FROM_SYSTEM_ERROR 0
#endif

using std::cerr;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main(/*int argc, char** argv*/) {
    int rv = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    errno = 0;

    try {
        std::ifstream ifs;
        ifs.exceptions(std::ios::badbit | std::ios::failbit);
        ifs.open("DOESN'T EXIST");

    } catch (const std::ios_base::failure& e) {

#if (HAS_IOS_BASE_FAILURE_DERIVED_FROM_SYSTEM_ERROR)
        //
        // e.code() is only available if the lib actually follows iso §27.5.3.1.1
        // and derives ios_base::failure from system_error
        // like e.g. libc++
        // http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/ios?revision=193085&view=markup
        // (line 415)
        //
        // and not keeps on deriving it directly from runtime_error
        // like libstdc++
        // https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/ios_base.h#L209
        //
        cout << "libc++ error #"    << e.code().value()  
                << ' '              << e.code().message()
                << ',' << endl << "    ";
#endif
        cout << "libc error #"      << (rv = errno)
                << ": "             << ::strerror(errno)
                << endl;

        cout << "handled" << endl;
    } 

    return rv;
}
```

using the the new e.code() semantics yields (with clang 3.4 and libc++ 1101) only the first line of

```
libc++ error #1 unspecified iostream_category error,
    libc error #2: No such file or directory
handled
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dc83f92f81952ea)

So even if one's lucky enough to have a std:: implementation that cares about iso §27.5.3.1.1 and actually derives ios_base::failure from system_error, the msg generated is too poor to be presented to users.

The only thing to be discussed is how the libc messages are best incorporated into wrapper classes.

Comment: Errors should be written to an error stream (such as `stderr`) with either `cerr` or `clog`.

Comment: Unless it is the regular output of the program, as it is the case here.

Comment: Indeed that **is not** regular output. Therefore, you should write it to a separated stream (I might redirect `stdout` to focus only on `stderr` to cleanly see whether the program succeded or not).

Comment: And indeed that is regular output of this program that is meant to test exceptions.

Comment: Then why does `std::terminate` write to `stderr`?

Comment: @Solkar, why do you think this is a test program meant to test exceptions?

Comment: Well... because it does?

Comment: Your answer/program is a test program, but @black is pointing out that the OP's code (which is what you should be reviewing - and that is what I meant when I said *why do you think this is a test program*) should write to stderr.

Comment: Good to know there is some movement towards a better standard in the future. I'm selecting your answer as the accepted, even though I'll remain using `strerror` for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid, no. [`iostream`s are not designed for exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180268/why-are-c-stl-iostreams-not-exception-friendly), which were added later, so you can easily understand why error messages are not helpful.
Moreover, you must explicitly ask for them in order to be thrown; otherwise, the default behavior is kept, that is querying the state of the stream.

The "modern" way is using `<system_error>` (as `std::thread` does, for example): as you have correctly pointed out, though, it isn't that higher level and modern.

The best solution is to use `boost::filesystem` which does throw exceptions, uses iterators and so on. Another solution might be wrapping it on your own, but it'd be worthless and I wouldn't suggest that unless required.